# about the proof of existence of weak solution of linear hyperbolic equation ( via Galerkin method)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In the classical PDE book of evans in the chapter 7 he proves using Galerkin method the existence of weak solution to the linear hyperbolic equation. In the page 385 (edition of 1998 ) he writes

Integrating by parts twice with respect to $t$ the equation

$$ \int_{0}^{T} \langle u'', v\rangle + B[u,v;t] \ dt = \int_{0}^{T} (f,v) \ dt$$
we obtain :

$$ \int_{0}^{T} \langle v'', u\rangle + B[u,v;t] \ dt \int_{0}^{T} (f,v) \ dt - (u(0), v'(0)) + \langle u' (0),  v(0)\rangle$$.

for $v \in C^{2}([0,T]; H^{1}_{0}(U))$ with $v(T) = v'(T) = 0$

How to prove this "integration by part formula"? Someone can give me a hint ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this [one](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=13&ved=0CDwQFjACOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucdavis.edu%2F~hunter%2Fpdes%2Fch6A.pdf&ei=3x_QUcSjF4TY8gTml4HYDQ&usg=AFQjCNEaDhSkJuDUeCpog0zeoZgDzkAPNA&sig2=G3_D74YrAm16VdKbEgxaoA) Theorem 6.40 or [this](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/The_Bochner_integral.html?id=CX1YAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) pages 181-182. You could try also type Bochner Integral on google or Bochner Intgration Parts. I did it and I found a lot of things.

Comment: If this don't help you, please leave a comment and I try to help you with the calculations (now I don't have time).